# About blender eevee light shadow problem ,lighting produces incorrect shadows on objects

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

There was a problem previewing EEVEE. The shadow produced by light shining on an object will not change the shadow of the object by adjusting the size of the light. When this problem occurred before, I would solve it by clicking on the camera, but today this method does not work. This error occurs similar to when you accidentally open the timeline while previewing eevee.

I want to ask if this can be solved? Thank you everyone[image]
[image]

The two scenes have the same lighting, but different effects

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which one the desired effect is, check whether Render properties -> Shadows -> Soft Shadows is ticked.

Comment: Yes, it's always on